# Replacing a Novoferm garage door lock

Tags: doors, garage, lock

[image: Garage door lock]

[image: Garage door handle]

We've lost the key to our Novoferm garage door lock and as the company that installed it quoted over a hundred pounds to fit a replacement I thought I would get the lock and fit it myself.

I took the handle off by removing the screw that goes through on the internal side of the door, and removed the nut from the centre of the rectangular lock housing. I also took the small screw out from the side (foreground in the picture). However there did not seem to be any way of removing the lock cylinder without bending the metal tabs that held the 'lid' of the housing in place.

My first questions is, is it possible to remove the cylinder? Or do I need to buy an entire new lock - i.e. the whole rectangular block?

My second question is, can anyone tell me the name of this lock fitting, so that I can speak to suppliers or search for it online?

Regarding further pictures of the mechanism, that's about all there is to it. The other side looks identical to the photographed side except there is no slot-headed screw.

I'm guessing this is a fairly commonplace mechanism?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Suggesting sources for parts isn't a good fit for our site. On actually getting the mechanism apart, a couple more images from different angles might help. (If you can't post more pictures, post URLs and someone will be along to edit them in.)

Answer (score 1):

That's a Euro-style lock cylinder. It is normally held in place by a setscrew clamping it into the lock, but you may have to substantially disassemble the lock before you can get to that screw.

If you can't figure out how to remove the cylinder, I'd suggest dismounting the whole lock body from the door and bringing it to a locksmith. That will save you the "on site service" fees.

Rekeying double-sided Euro cylinders is a skill not all locksmiths in the US have. Single-sided, with keyway on one end and thumb turn on the other, are simpler.